# How to get a BATCH file executed from a web page?

Tags: r, batch-file, html

I have a one line batch file that I want to call from a web page via a button what is the best way to achieve this?

The BATCH File is as follows:

```
c:\R\bin\Rscript.exe "c:\Users\user\Desktop\Shares.R"
```

Or is it possible just to call the R script straight from the web page and skip the BATCH file altogether, Can this be done? It is all being done on a local host so I don't think there should be a problem with permissions etc...

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Anthony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add

```
<form action="YOUR_BATCH_FILE"><input type="submit"/></form>
```

to your HTML and then configure your web-server to treat your batch script as a CGI program. How this is done depends on the web server you are using.